# Consider the divides-relationship on $A =\{1, 2, 3, 4, 6\}$. Use the notation $D(x, y)$ to mean $x$ divides $y$.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I am having a lot of trouble trying to understand this problem on my discrete mathematics homework.

My homework is on subsets, functions, and properties of relationships.

Now what it want's to know is if the divides-relationship on $A=\{1,2,3,4,6\}$. is transitive, symmetric, and or reflexive. 
I do not understand what a divides relationship is, at least I think I don't, and I say that because I did notice every member of the set divides evenly into $12$.

Can someone help explain to me what a divides-relationship is, and what makes it transitive, symmetric, and or reflexive?

Comment: for example 2 divides 4, 1 divides 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The divide relationship means D(x,y) means $x|y$.

Is it reflexive?

Is it true that $x|x$ always?  If so, yes.  If not no.  (Does 1|1? Does 2|2? Does 3.....etc.)

Is it symetric?

Is it true that if $x|y$ then $y|x$?  If so, yes, If not no.  Can you provide a counterexample? Can you prove it.  (Hint:  If $3|6$ does $6|3$).

Is it transitive?

Is it true that if $x|y$ and $y|z$ then $x|z$?  Can you prove it?  Can you give a counter example?  (Hint: if $x|y$ then $y = nx$.  If $y|z$ then $z = my$.  Can you express $z$ in terms of $x$?)

Comment: Thank you, this actually really helped me understand what was being asked.